# Latex font not scalable for report class title?

Tags: report, latex, texmaker

I'm trying to run the following code in texmaker on Ubuntu Linux

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\title{Nice New Title}
\author{Some Clever Dude}
\maketitle
Will this now work?
\end{document}
```

But am getting the following error.

```
! Font OT1/phv/m/n/12=phvr7t at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
```

Is there something restrictive in the report class that causes this error?  All I want is the entire report in San-Serif or Helvetica Font.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that I was missing the package

texlive-fonts-recommended

As soon as I installed it, errors went away!

J